# Do you build a Git repository with the bower_components folder?

Tags: git, bower

So perhaps this is a stupid question, I'm brand new to Git, and fairly new to bower. I've done a bunch of google searching and can't find an understandable answer at this time, so please be kind:

Using bower to install several repositories, such as jquery, foundation, and meanmenu, I've disocered that if I now create a repository out of my project, I find that it complains about a file within the bower folder (meanmenu's readme file, of all things).

So a warning ticked off in my head when I realized, if bower is supposed to be managing those files separately, than they probably shouldn't be included in my git repository, correct? So does that mean I have to somehow exclude the bower folder from project within git? so that when I create the whole thing, I leave out bower? and then if someone downloads my project, bower will auto install the necessary required packages for them?

Or am I way off base here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right, it's pretty typical to have git ignore certain files/folders. For example, another package manager called npm creates a folder named `node_modules` that is generally excluded from git repos.

Create a file called `.gitignore` in the base of your git repo and put the name of the directory or files you want excluded in the file.

Some examples of gitignore files here: https://github.com/github/gitignore